# Search a string for words starting/ending with special regular expression characters containing parenthesis

Tags: php, regex

I have a php string that looks like this :

```
$str = Toto| Tata Titi (Tété)
```

In my code, a lot of strings could look like that, So I want to check if my string starts with the word "Toto" and ends with the word "(Tété)" (with parenthesis and the "é").

"Toto" could change over time, that's why I used the variable `$myVar`.

So to check all that, I wrote this regex :

```
$match = preg_match('/\^ '. $myVar.'(.*?)\\\\\(Tété\\)$/', $str)
```

But it doesn't work at all, the output is `false` all the time.

Please, where I'm wrong ?

Comment: `\^` should be `^`. You also have *way* too many `\\\\ ` before your `(`

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://regex101.com/ is a good resource for experimenting with regex. You can test your regex against custom input, and it gives a descriptive explanation of what each character does.

In particular, the regex `^Toto.*\(Tété\)$` checks for `Toto` at the beginning of a string, any non-line break characters, and `(Tété)` at the end.

If you want to make sure `Toto` and `(Tété)` are separated from the characters following/proceeding them by a space, you can use `^Toto (.* )?\(Tété\)$`.

Since you're putting backslashes in a string, you need an additional backslash to escape the backslash. So you want to use `^Toto.*\\(Tété\\)$` or `^Toto (.* )?\\(Tété\\)$`.